# What's the difference between point and shoot camera brands?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, nikon, fujifilm

Our old camera broke, so we decided to buy a new one, but we can't choose between similar models from Fujifilm, Canon, and Nikon. Many people advised me to get the Canon, but in my opinion the Fujifilm looks better. What's the difference between these brands, and in general is there a particular reason I should pick one over another?

Comment: Deepsy, please read the accepted answer to [How do I choose a point and shoot camera under $400](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34289/17441).

Comment: @EsaPaulasto , I did a research and sadly I couldn't choose between these 3 cameras. They're almost with the same specifications and I can't choose, so I'm asking for advice.

Comment: @Deepsy We're happy to give advice about photography and about camera gear, but specific recommendations do not fit our question and answer format. As models change quickly, such advice is quickly dated, and in any case is highly subjective and personal — what may be best for you won't be for someone else. *And*, in forums which do encourage this kind of thing, it often comes down to flamewars about brands, or everyone posting about how their favorite brand is the best whenever it comes up, not actualkt helpful expert advice. We want to avoid all of that.

Comment: Instead of asking what to buy, ask about specific things which you think might help with your decision if you understood better. Or, if you can't really find any such differences in your narrowed set of options, **congratulations! You are done.** They are all fine cameras from respected brands, so get whichever speaks to you the most (or is cheaper, or nearby, or whatever). Then you can get out of camera shopping and on to _photography_, which is what really matters.

Comment: On the edit.... well, we [have a similar one for DSLR brands](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon) and that worked out pretty well....

Comment: @mattdm - Let's see how it goes then... :)

Comment: I think the question serves the purpose of allowing us to say "there really isn't much difference" and point those who ask similar questions here in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The camera you should buy is the one you *want*  to use!

Within any given price point competing brands of cameras deliver generally equivalent results.  What's most important is to go to a camera dealer, physically compare the options and purchase what appeals to you most *for any reason whatsoever!*

Remember, the camera that is used will always take better pictures than one that is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Brands specifically? The only think I can think of is menu and button lay out. That's it. They pretty much all do the same thing.

If you're more familiar with one brand and find it easier to use, maybe that one is best for you.

A lot of brands buy lenses from 1 manufacturer and re-badge it. If you come across different brands with the same zoom range (in focal lengths) and apertures, it's likely it's the same lens.

Compact cameras are categorized into different functions. Examples are:

- Zoom
- Waterproof
- Front facing LCD
- WiFi
- Colors

The list goes on... Higher end ones generally have a brighter (smaller f stop) aperture.

When looking for compact cameras, it's probably better to look at functionality. But, familiarity might be better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike for a DSLR or mirrorless camera, brands matter little. What you need to do is shop for a particular model that has the features you want and focal-range that suits your photography. For a interchangeable lens camera, the brand matters more because you are buying into a system, something which is rarely share except for Micro Four-Thirds.

While compact cameras are generally quite similar from one another, there are a few models which distinguish themselves by their feature-set and image-quality compromises. Among the compact and ultra-compact category, there are much more compromises than on the high-end.

There are two key components to look after: the sensor and lens. You may notice that nearly every small camera has the same sensor size but there are exceptions. A handful use 1/1.7" or 2/3" sensor-sizes paired with fast lenses which let them shoot at lower light than others.

At this time, [Sony](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/sony/rx100ii) and [Canon](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/canon/g1x) are the only ones to make a model with notably larger sensor and a zoom lens but you can get a compact with a [fixed lens and large sensor](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?sensorcrop=1.5:max&lensattachment=fixed) from several brands. These models use the same sensor-size as DSLR giving incredible quality to their images at the cost of a set angle-of-view.

Once you know what features you are looking for you can easily [search for them](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) on my site and the results show you the sensor-size. As a general rule, the larger the sensor the higher the image-quality.