# What camera should I buy as a first year animation student?

Tags: film, macro, zoom, camera

I am a first year animation student and my question isn’t very specific but I just need some advice on buying a camera as I want to make the right decision.

First of all, I’m a beginner in photography (as you can tell) and I’m looking for a camera that ranges between 250 - 350€.

I would like to be able to film with it, take photos for animations and for it to be easy to use. There are a lot of cameras out there and I’m getting a bit lost and don’t want to make the wrong decision. Any advice? I also love taking macro pictures and for the camera to have a good zoom without a lens? But these arn’t mainly important.

Comment: You may want to post this question over at Video.SE. Finding a camera that can produce "quality" video for animation is off-topic here at Photo.SE. As for finding a camera for photography, that question has been answered here (https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34289/how-do-i-choose-a-point-and-shoot-camera-under-400). And finally, the ease of use of a tool (like a camera) is directly proportional to the skill of the wielder. Feel free to ask questions here as you learn.

Comment: Questions about taking stills to use in a time lapse video are perfectly on topic here. Product recommendations, however, are not. They're not on topic over at video.SE either.

Answer (score 3):

If you are enrolled in a photography/videography program, I'd expect the institution to provide guidance on the equipment necessary to complete the program.  If nothing else, a quick discussion with your instructor should lead you down the right path.

A few random people on the internet can of course make recommendations, but we aren't in your program and don't know what would work best for it.

Beyond that, if you do want to do general research, we have a **ton** of existing information on this site to help first time camera buyers, for example [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr) or try the search function.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for specific features.

- Manual settings. Iso, Aperture, Shutter speed.
- Manual white balance.
- If it is a still image camera, in my opinion, 10Mpx good enough, it can give you more resolution than a 4K camera, but probably you want to go for a 24Mpx one to have some more room to work with.
- One camera that can be plugged while working, because if you need to move the camera to change batteries it can ruin your work.
- Also, one that can send the photos directly to a computer and has a live view on the computer.

---

Now you have a specific list too look for.

Answer (score 0):

The price range you are talking about is so low that you'd probably be better off saving your money for a better camera (some day) and, for now, using the one in your phone. A decent phone camera, these days, can come close to what you can get from a basic compact digital camera. Your budget could get you a decent auxiliary lens or other accessories to improve your mobile photography. You might otherwise look at a used APS-C mirrorless camera with a basic lens. You could add to that set over time.

Comment: Not true. You could buy a new Nikon or Canon bundle with 350 euros.